# Pandas to_datetime: not being able to specify origin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `seconds` in my DataFrame which shows elapsed seconds from 1.1.2009. I need to convert those seconds to datetime in format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I have tried:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["seconds"], unit="s", origin=pd.Timestamp('2009-01-01'))
```

But this throws exception:

```
object is not compatible with origin='2009-01-01 00:00:00'; It must be numeric with unit specified
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert column to numbers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html), for `origin` is psosible use `string`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'seconds':['0','1','2','3']})

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["seconds"].astype(int), unit="s", origin='2009-01-01')
print (df)
  seconds                date
0       0 2009-01-01 00:00:00
1       1 2009-01-01 00:00:01
2       2 2009-01-01 00:00:02
3       3 2009-01-01 00:00:03
```

Comment: Man, how fast do you think? Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Engineer - actually read error more times and try understand it ;)